# Bootstrap menu navigation breaks for tablet version

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap nav to show menu, In my case my menu will be large with few sub-menus's each having about 10 submenus.

I have set up example on jsbin. For some reason tab & mobile version menu is not showing.

http://jsbin.com/hobuzasire/2/edit

Actual issue I am facing is that this menu doesn't shows all the menu items and even doesn't allow to scroll through all menu items.

How can I make this menu for tab & mobile version scrollable in case it is larger than screen, so that user can scroll through all menu items.

Also I want to show mobile version of menu when screen size is 1199px by default it works at 768px;

**Update**:
This css property from bootstrap class is limiting the menu height, How can I make menu grow with items and add scrollable when menu is larger than screen size (Height)

```
.navbar-collapse{
    max-height: 340px;
}
```

Comment: Your using `<i class="fa fa-bars">` but don't include the Font Awesome CSS.

Comment: What about the actual question, regarding menu not showing on tablet properly,

Answer (score 1):

The button is there and works, you just can't see it, because the icon font you are using is not included in your file. Be sure to include FontAwesome css link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Once you drop that in, the button shows up as expected.